# Merge three mysql entries to one entry

Tags: php, mysql, merge, create-table

I have 3 or 4 entries with the same name of a person an different other entries.

```
A    B    C          
---- ---- -----------
a    01    XXX 
a    02    XYZ
a    03    ABC
```

How can I merge them by selecting the a which is always the same in A to a structure like this:

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  --- 
a    01   02   03   XXX  XYZ  ABC
```

Hope you can help me getting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative Solution**

If you have variable number of entries for different users then use GROUP_CONCAT FUNCTION. It is easier way (with some processing in php) than to make dynamic number of columns in sql.

```
SELECT A,GROUP_CONCAT(B) B, GROUP_CONCAT(C) C
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY A;
```

The result will be like:-
A     B             C
---   ---          --- 
a    01,02,03   XXX,XYZ,ABC

You can further process it in php code to get column separated.

Comment: I have this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/245f1/17 but i need all DATETIME in a new column with the title from ACTIONTEXT for every DRIVERNAME

Comment: can you post the result you expect? I mean the exected result table from your fiddle??